# Make a photo display when pushing a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm a newbie when it comes to building apps.  Is there any way to make an image appear when a button is pressed?  I already have the button displaying text on a label when pushed.  Here is my code for the button:

```
- (IBAction)ClickMe:(id)sender 
{
    _resultLabel.text = self.tempText.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the image into a uiimageview. Set it hidden at the start. When you press the button, unhide, if pressed again hide (toggle)

Comment: SO I click, "hidden" in the drawing section.  Then what?

Answer (score 0):

first create an imageView and assign an image to it .

```
@interface UIImageViewCustom : UIViewController {
 UIImageView *imageView ;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.jpeg"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,40,200,100)];  
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

and then add it to view when button is pressed .

```
- (IBAction)ClickMe:(id)sender 
{
    _resultLabel.text = self.tempText.text;
    [self.view addSubView:imageView];
}
```

Comment: Thank You,  is there a way you can elaborate more?  I just started programming a couple of weeks ago, so assume that you're working with someone that knows barely anything.

Comment: Why'd you do this on a subclass of UIImageView? Did you mean to subclass UIViewController?

Comment: @AnthonyPicone : I have a created an object of UIImageView and assigned proper frame , image , etc to it . Then I added it to the self.view which is the view controller's view as a subview .

Comment: @ChrisLoonam : Oh Sorry , thats actually a UIViewController. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageView.hidden = NO;
```